# Bash test: what does "=~" do?

Tags: bash, test

```
#!/bin/bash
INT=-5

if [[ "$INT" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then

echo "INT is an integer."

else

echo "INT is not an integer." >&2

exit 1

fi
```

What does the leading `~` do in the starting regular expression?

Answer (score 122):

The `~` is actually part of the operator `=~`, which performs a regular expression match of the string to its left to the extended regular expression on its right.

```
[[ "string" =~ pattern ]]
```

Note that the string should be quoted, and the regular expression shouldn't be quoted (unless you want to match literal strings).

A similar operator is used in the Perl programming language and several other general-purpose and domain-specific languages to perform regular expression matching.

The regular expressions understood by `bash` are the same as those that GNU `grep` understands with the `-E` flag, i.e. the extended set of regular expressions.

---

Somewhat off-topic, but good to know:

When matching against a regular expression containing capturing groups, the part of the string captured by each group is available in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. The zeroth/first entry in this array corresponds to `&` in the replacement pattern of `sed`'s substitution command (or `$&` in Perl), which is the bit of the string that matches the pattern, while the entries at index 1 and onwards correspond to `\1`, `\2`, etc. in a `sed` replacement pattern (or `$1`, `$2` etc. in Perl), i.e. the bits matched by each parenthesis.

Example:

```
string=$( date +%T )

if [[ "$string" =~ ^([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])$ ]]; then
  printf 'Got %s, %s and %s\n' \
    "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
```

This may output

```
Got 09, 19 and 14
```

if the current time happens to be 09:19:14.

The `REMATCH` bit of the `BASH_REMATCH` array name comes from "Regular Expression Match", i.e. "RE-Match".

---

In non-`bash` Bourne-like shells, one may also use `expr` for limited regular expression matching (using only basic regular expressions).

A small example:

```
$ string="hello 123 world"
$ expr "$string" : ".*[^0-9]\([0-9][0-9]*\)"
123
```

Comment: It's the same as what `grep -E` understands only on GNU systems and only when using an unquoted variable as the pattern `[[ $var = $pattern ]]` (see `[[ 'a b' =~ a\sb ]]` vs `p='a\sb'; [[ 'a b' =~ $p ]]`). Also beware that shell quoting affects the meaning of RE operators and that some characters need to be quoted for the shell tokenising that may affect the RE processing. `[[ '\' =~ [\/] ]]` returns false. `ksh93` has even worse issues. See `zsh` (or bash 3.1) for a saner approach where shell and RE quoting are clearly separate. The `[` builtin of `zsh` and `yash` also have a `=~` operator.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How is it "saner" that both of this match in zsh?: `[[ "This is a fine mess." =~  T.........fin*es*    ]]; [[ "This is a fine mess." =~  T.........fin\*es\*  ]]`. Or that a quoted `*` also match? `[[ "This is a fine mess." =~ "T.........fin*es*"   ]]`.

Comment: It's saner (IMO) in that it's much simpler rules. Shell quoting and RE escaping are clearly separate. In `[[ a =~ .* ]]` or `[[ a =~ '.*' ]]` or `[[ a =~ \.\* ]]`, the same `.*` RE is passed to the `=~` operator. OTH, in `bash`, `[[ '\' =~ [)] ]]` returns an error, would you know without trying it whether `[[ '\' =~ [\)] ]]` matches?  How about `[[ '\' =~ [\/] ]]` (it does in ksh93). How about `c='a-z'; [[ a =~ ["$c"] ]]` (compare with the `=` operator)? See also: `[[ '\' =~ [^]"."] ]]` which returns false... Note that you can do `shopt -s compat31` in `bash` to get the `zsh` behaviour.

Comment: `zsh`/`bash -o compat31`'s behaviour for `[[ a =~ '.*' ]]` is also consistent with `[ a '=~' '.*' ]` (for `[` implementations that support `=~`) or `expr a : '.*'`. OTOH, it's not consistent with `[[ a = '*' ]]` vs `[[ a = * ]]` (but then, globs are part of the shell language, while REs are not).

Comment: To deal with characters in the pattern that might be interpreted by the shell, it's often recommended to do something like this: `pat="..."; if [[ "$string" =~ $pat ]]; then ...`. (@StéphaneChazelas's topmost comment suggested it, I'm just emphasizing it.)

Answer (score 11):

You should read the bash man pages, under the `[[ expression ]]` section.

`An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string  to  the  right  of  the operator  is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).`

Long story short, `=~` is an operator, just like `==` and `!=`. It has nothing to do with the actual regex in the string to its right.

Comment: Can you figure out some examples demonstrating the use of `=~` in real life...?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I use it fairly often in scripts that put the output from a command into a variable. Then the variable is checked to see if it matches some string pattern. This is useful for example if you want to take some action based on some error output from that command.

Comment: @Sokel For some, “RTFM” is easier said than done. ⋯ `man [[ expresssion ]]` and `man [[` return nothing.  `help [[` returns useful information—since `[[` an internal bash command—but does not say whether `=~` uses basic or extended regex syntax. ⋯ The text you quoted is from the **bash** man page.  I realize you said “read the bash man pages” but at first, I thought you meant read the man pages within bash. At any rate, `man bash` returns a huge file, which is 4139 lines (72 pages) long. It can be searched by pressing `/▒▒▒`, which takes a regex, the flavor of which—like `=~`—is not specified.

Comment: a link to the page where that does appeared would have helped the answer