# Compare string with regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I would like to check hostnames to make sure they follow the standard naming convention in `Bash Shell`.

Let say the hostname is `ab-cde-01`

```
wolf@linux:~$ h='ab-cde-01'
wolf@linux:~$ echo $h
ab-cde-01
wolf@linux:~$
```

I started by building if else loop and it's working just fine.

```
wolf@linux:~$ if [ $h = 'ab-cde-01' ]; then
> echo $h is a valid name
> else
> echo $h is an INVALID name
> fi
ab-cde-01 is a valid name
wolf@linux:~$
```

However, when I try to use regex to replace numbers with [0-9], I'm getting an invalid name.

```
wolf@linux:~$ if [ $h = 'ab-cde-0[0-9]' ]; then
> echo $h is a valid name
> else
> echo $h is an INVALID name
> fi
ab-cde-01 is an INVALID name
wolf@linux:~$
```

**update 1: =~ operator**

`=~` operator used as suggested ...

```
wolf@linux:~$ if [ $h =~ 'ab-cde-0[0-9]' ]; then
> echo $h is a valid name
> else
> echo $h is an INVALID name
> fi
bash: [: =~: binary operator expected
ab-cde-01 is an INVALID name
wolf@linux:~$
```

**update 2: double bracket**

```
wolf@linux:~$ if [[ $h =~ 'ab-cde-0[0-9]' ]]; then
> echo $h is a valid name
> else
> echo $h is an INVALID name
> fi
ab-cde-01 is an INVALID name
wolf@linux:~$
```

1. What's wrong in this code?
2. How to fix it?
3. Is this the right/most efficient way to check hostname against certain standard?

**update 3: Actual answer for my own reference too**

```
wolf@linux:~$ if [[ $h =~ ab-cde-0[0-9] ]]; then
> echo $h is a valid name
> else
> echo $h is an INVALID name
> fi
ab-cde-01 is a valid name
wolf@linux:~$
```

Lessons learned

1. Use double bracket instead of single bracket
2. No quote in regex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash test: what does "=~" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340440/bash-test-what-does-do). Not exactly the same question but the answer will help you ;-)

Comment: Please edit your question to include which shell you are using; the answer may depend on it.

Comment: @AdminBee, `Bash Shell`. Question updated

Comment: Thanks @pLumo, but `=~` operator produces an error in the code.

`bash: [: =~: binary operator expected`

Comment: Then the answer @pLumo pointed you too will likely solve your problem. Note that you must then use the `[[ ... ]]` double bracket test operator.

Comment: @update 2, from the accepted answer of my link: "Note that the string should be quoted, and that the regular expression shouldn't be quoted." (double quotes if you want to expand variables !!)

Comment: Thanks @pLumo, it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final attempt is the closest, but still has a couple of issues.

Fundamentally, it's not working because you are quoting the regex.  It needs to be like this:

```
MATCH='ab-cde-0[0-9]'
if [[ "$h" =~ $MATCH ]];then
```

But there's still an issue there, because you haven't anchored the regex (meaning it can match in the middle of a given string), so the above would still pass for `h=foo-ab-cde07bar`.

Anchoring is done like so:

```
MATCH='^ab-cde-0[0-9]$'
if [[ "$h" =~ $MATCH ]];then
```

But in this limited example, you don't even need to use regex, you can use glob matching instead.  This should work for what you have presented:

```
MATCH='ab-cde-0[0-9]'
if [[ "$h" = $MATCH ]];then
```

*NB: I have quoted the `$h` string in all examples, because this is good practice.*

*Edit: I've now defined the matchers as variables, per suggestion from **ilkkachu***

Comment: best way around the regex quoting issue is to put the regex in a variable, and expand it without quotes, i.e. `re='^ab-cde-0[0-9]$'; if [[ $h =~ $re ]]; then ...`

Comment: Thanks @bxm, it works on Linux, but the same code didn't work on Windows cygwin (invalid name). Any reason for that?

Comment: @ilkkachu good point, thanks ... updated

Comment: @Wolf Hmm maybe some peculiarity with how cygwin is handling things.  You could try my latest edit where the matchers are quoted.