# Bash - What h[aeiou] does in the [[ =~ ]] expression?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, test

I am new at unix, I'm trying to learn the bash language, and when I went to the "Testing expression", I found this one:

```
[[ "whatever" =~ h[aeiou] ]]
```

I already read the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340440/bash-test-what-does-do), so I understand what the operator =~ does. After running the previous command, the output of `echo $?` is `0`, meaning the condition inside the `[[ ]]` is met. If instead I type

```
[[ "whatever" =~ h[sdfghjkl] ]]
```

the output of `echo $?` is `1`, so the condition was not met.

So, I would like to know what the `h[aeiou]` and `h[sdfghjkl]` are.
Is `h` a predefined function inside the `[[ ]]` expression? And if so, what is it doing? If not, what `h[aeiou]` and `h{sdfghjkl]` actually are?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first command will evaluate as true if the string "whatever" contains the letter `h` followed by a vowel. Second command looks for `h` followed by your list of letters. `h` is not a predefined function but is part of the regular expression to match against.

Comment: They are regular expressions.  `h[aeiou]` matches a pair of letters, the left letter being `h` and the right-hand letter being one of those listed between `[` and `]` (an English vowel letter).  `h[sdfghjkl]` is exactly the same, but with matching the right-hand letter with a list of different letters between `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it says in the other post, the `=~` does a pattern match, with the right-side operand being a regular expression (regex).

The brackets in `h[aeiou]` are part of the regex syntax, there's no named function there. `h[aeiou]`, matches an `h` and then any single one of `aeiou`, so `whatever` matches because it contains an `h` followed by an `a`.

You're going to hear about regexes, so it might be worth looking into them a bit:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
- https://regexone.com/
- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

(The Wikipedia page seems to also go in the formal details, don't get too caught up in that.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It solved my question, and thanks for the provided links. :]

Comment: @andr.lex, note that `=~` doesn't require a full-string match, so indeed `[[ whatever =~ h[aeiou] ]]` matches. That's unlike most contexts where shell patterns are used. (The original version of this answer, before terdon fixed it, said it wouldn't match, and I don't know what I was thinking there.)